# FIlter data based on month and ID and sum in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filter, jupyter-notebook

`ID.    Email.        Amount   Date
1.      wi@gn.c.      20      26-11-19 12.06.36.726000
2.      wi@gn.c.      40      26-12-19 12.06.37.293000
3.      by@gn.c.      50      26-11-19 12.06.37.960000
4.      wi@gn.c.      20      26-01-20 12.06.51.306000
5.      wi@gn.c.      60      26-02-20 12.06.52.458000
6.      by@gn.c.      15      26-08-19 12.06.58.397000
7.      wi@gn.c.      37      26-12-19 12.07.00.191000
5.      wi@gn.c.      60      26-02-20 12.06.52.458000
6.      by@gn.c.      15      26-08-19 12.06.58.397000
7.      wi@gn.c.      37      26-12-19 12.07.00.191000`

I need to get the total amount for each email address for the past 1 month, 3 month and 6 months. I have tried several combinations of commands but I am lost now.

In another answer `df.groupby('Email')['Amount'].sum().reset_index()` works but i need to add the sum based on the 1 Month, 3 months and 6 months.

The expected result will look like this

`ID.    Email.        Total for past 1 Month    Total for past 3 Month    Total for past 6 Month
1.      wi@gn.c.      20                          40                        60
3.      by@gn.c.      50                          50                        100`

NB: the final figures are not exactly correct, I am just trying to paint a picture of what I am trying to do.

Comment: I guess you could use a pivot table

Comment: @davidbilla, thanks for the suggestion, i will read on it and see how that goes, but i am relatively new to python, i am a java developer that needs to do some few manipulations to some data in python

Comment: I would suggest starting with just one of those columns and using df[df[date column]>= x months ago].groupby ...

Comment: @WinfredAdrah Please see my answer below. There may be a more efficient solution for this.

Comment: @davidbilla, i did the calculation in excel manually, but it did not match the result you had

Comment: I guess the `df.last()` is not working as I was expecting. I can look into it later. So, you need to base the 1 month, 3 month and 6 month frame based on current date?

Comment: @davidbilla Yes. It needs to be based on the current date.

Comment: @WinfredAdrah please see updated answer, hope it works for you

Comment: @davidbilla, please one last question, i have another field that Transaction Status, where i have Transaction Successful or Transaction not successful, how do i filter only Transaction Succesful with the answer you have given. I have tried `df[df['Transaction status'] == Transaction Succesful]` . df_1mo = df.loc[end - pd.DateOffset(months=1): end].df[df['Transaction status'] == Transaction Succesful.groupby('Email')['Amount'].agg(total_1mo=np.sum)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps: First convert your 'Date' column to DateTimeIndex. Then you have to segregate your data into groups of 1 month, 3 months and 6 months and create 3 dfs. Aggregate these 3 dfs by sum of 'Amount'.  At last, merge all these 3 dfs on 'Email' column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,'wi@gn.c.',20,'26-11-19 12.06.36.726000'],
                   [2,'wi@gn.c.',40,'26-12-19 12.06.37.293000'],
                   [3,'by@gn.c.',50,'26-11-19 12.06.37.960000'],
                   [4,'wi@gn.c.',20,'26-01-20 12.06.51.306000'],
                   [5,'wi@gn.c.',60,'26-02-20 12.06.52.458000'],
                   [6,'by@gn.c.',15,'26-08-19 12.06.58.397000'],
                   [7,'wi@gn.c.',37,'26-12-19 12.07.00.191000'],
                   [6,'wi@gn.c.',60,'26-02-20 12.06.52.458000'],
                   [7,'by@gn.c.',15,'26-08-19 12.06.58.397000'],
                   [8,'wi@gn.c.',37,'26-12-19 12.07.00.191000']],
                  columns=['ID','Email','Amount','Date'])

# convert your 'Date' to datetimeindex
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format = '%d-%m-%y %H.%M.%S.%f')
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

# create dfs from base df for past 1 month, 3 months and 6 months data and aggregate by sum of 'Amount'
end = pd.datetime.now()
df_1mo = df.loc[end - pd.DateOffset(months=1): end].groupby('Email')['Amount'].agg(total_1mo=np.sum)
df_3mo = df.loc[end - pd.DateOffset(months=3): end].groupby('Email')['Amount'].agg(total_3mo=np.sum)
df_6mo = df.loc[end - pd.DateOffset(months=6): end].groupby('Email')['Amount'].agg(total_6mo=np.sum)

# merge all 3 dfs on 'Email'
print(df_1mo.merge(df_3mo, on='Email', how='outer').merge(df_6mo, on='Email', how='outer').fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
          total_1mo  total_3mo  total_6mo
Email                                    
wi@gn.c.      120.0      254.0        274
by@gn.c.        0.0        0.0         50
```

- In the last 1 month range (Feb 11-Mar 11) you have only 2 rows with
  `Date` as 02/26, both with `Email` wi@gn.c. and the sum of `Amount`
  is 60+60=120.
- In the last 3 month range (Dec 11-Mar 11) you have 6
  rows with `Date` as 02/26/2020, 01/26/2020 and 12/26/2019 all with
  the same `Email` wi@gn.c. and the sum of `Amount` is
  60+60+20+37+37+40=254.
- In the last 6 month range (Sep 11-Mar 11) you
  have 8 rows with `Date` as 02/26/2020, 01/26/2020, 12/26/2020 and
  11/26/2019. Of this one row is with `Email` by@gn.c. and `Amount` as 50. All other rows are with `Email` wi@gn.c. and the sum of `Amount` is 60+60+20+37+37+40+20=274.
- The other 2 rows with `Date` as
  08/26/2020 are not in this range of 6 months so they are excluded.

Hope this explains the answer. You can change the `end` date to a different date to make your baseline date. Here I have used current date as baseline date.

There may be a better efficient solution for this. But this should work based on your sample dataset. Let me know how it goes.

Update: min and max:

```
df_1mo = df.loc[end - pd.DateOffset(months=1): end].groupby('Email')['Amount'].agg(total_1mo=np.max)
df_3mo = df.loc[end - pd.DateOffset(months=3): end].groupby('Email')['Amount'].agg(total_3mo=np.max)
df_6mo = df.loc[end - pd.DateOffset(months=6): end].groupby('Email')['Amount'].agg(total_6mo=np.max)

# merge all 3 dfs on 'Email'
print(df_1mo.merge(df_3mo, on='Email', how='outer').merge(df_6mo, on='Email', how='outer').fillna(0))
```

Output:

```
          total_1mo  total_3mo  total_6mo
Email                                    
wi@gn.c.       60.0       60.0         60
by@gn.c.        0.0        0.0         50
```

Comment: Thank you for the update @davidbilla but I am getting the error `index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing`

i am looking it up to see if I can find the solution, but if you have the solution, i will really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: You have to sort the df using `df.sort_index(inplace=True)` before slicing it. Check updated solution.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am really grateful.

Comment: @WinfredAdrah Glad I was able to help!!

Comment: sorry i have to come back, but i need to get the min and max amount for the same periods, i have tried np.max and grouping by min(). but i am not really sure. Please let me know if this should be a separate question

Comment: @WinfredAdrah You want to have the min and max in the same resultant df? Can you post the expected df you are trying to get?

Comment: I want to get the Max Amount for each email for the past 1 month, 3 months and 6 months. I thought it will be very similar to this, but i am not sure what to change for the agg  and np.sum.

Comment: Or i can ask a new question and post the link here.

Comment: @WinfredAdrah You just have to replace `np.sum` with `np.min` or `np.max`. It should work just fine.

Comment: Wow, how come i did not think of that, i guess i was over thinking it, thank you, i have accepted the answer ass the correct answer. I cant upvote because i have just 15 reputations. Thanks

Comment: lol. i thought np.count will do the trick for me to get the counts for the various months, but it didnt, i get `module 'numpy' has no attribute 'count'`. i am probably asking too much now.

Comment: @WinfredAdrah Try `np.size` instead